# About "tolerant of"

Tags: prepositions

1. Alpine strawberries are tolerant of most soils
2. They need to be tolerant of different points of view

I think that "of" in each sentence doesn't function in a same way. I mean "of" could be interchangeable with "in" in the first sentence, but "of" in the second sentence couldn't be interchangeable with "in" but only with "about".

Is my thinking correct?

And I want to know what "of" is meant for in each sentence. I've already looked up "of" in dictionaries, but I 'm still not sure what definition of "of" in dictionaries would be fit with those two "of"s in the two sentences.

I myself guess "of" in the first sentence would function the same way "of" does in these sentences "He died of cancer" or "The kitchen is capable of catering for several hundred people" for expressing "integration of the subject and object of "of"" like "He + cancer" and "the kitchen + catering for several hundred people", but "of" in the second sentence would function the different way "of" does in these sentences "They approved of his choice" or "I'm thinking of it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your examples use **X is tolerant of Y** in the same way, and you can't use "in" or "about" in those sentences and have the exact same meaning.

- "Alpine strawberries are tolerant **in** most soils" is only permissible because strawberries are in soil, but it means the strawberries are tolerant without specifying what they are tolerant of -- perhaps they are tolerant of different weather regardless of what soil they are in.  **Tolerant of** most soils indicates that it is the soil types they are tolerant of.
- A person "tolerant **about** different points of view" is similar but vaguer than **of different points view**".